# getting an error on pushing the object inside the array in mongoose TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodejs-server

I was trying to push comment in the post schema my Post  schema looks like this

```js
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    },
    commments: [
        {
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Post' 
        },
    ],
},{
    timestamps:true
});
```

In the code I am finding the post and if there then pushing the comment

```
Post.findById(req.body.post, function(err, post){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if (post) {
            Comment.create({
                content: req.body.content,
                post: req.body.post,
                user: req.user._id
            }, function(err, comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(post);
                post.comments.push(comment);
                post.save();
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    });
```

I am getting an error message

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

I tried console logging the post
while console logging the post I am getting

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("64006ec38c0c7b43fcf42a64"),
  content: 'hehe',
  user: new ObjectId("63fa0b3732455636bcf01b00"),
  commments: [],
  createdAt: 2023-03-02T09:39:15.845Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-03-02T09:39:15.845Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

that comments is an array.
but while pushing it is showing it as undefined

Comment: what is the comments value? try to log it first, i affraid is undefined or null or else

Comment: Tried logging the post and comments both and it is working fine and comment are also getting stored inside the DB as I check inside the mongo DB compass

Comment: well, its may internet issue. anyway use `async` instead, if i am not wrong, `callback` will be removed and maybe already removed in specific version of mongoose.